# How to create subclass of SKSpriteNode in Swift 3

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, subclass, skspritenode

I've seen lots of similar questions to mine but they all seemed to be for older versions of Swift or for very different situations. In any case, none of the solutions worked for me.

I am building a simple SpriteKit game. Basically, all I want to do is add an attribute to the SKSpriteNode class: e.g.

```
let Ci = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CBlob")
Ci.name = "C1"
Ci.pitch = "middle C"
```

Currently, setting the name attribute works fine because SKSpriteNode has a name attribute. In Python I would just be able to declare the pitch attribute when instantiating the object. However, in Swift to add the pitch attribute I have tried to create a SKSpriteNode subclass.

```
class Blob : SKSpriteNode {
var pitch = "middle C"
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to initialise an instance of Blob. e.g.

```
let Ci = Blob(imageNamed: "CBlob")
```

I feel like I've tried every combination of super, override etc. but all result in errors.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: let Ci = ...  You really need to go back to basics.

Comment: If you could, I'd appreciate some elaboration ... I'm very new to swift. What's wrong with let? I thought let object still enables one to change the object's attributes?

Comment: Your code should work. What's the issue?

Comment: @modalmusic What errors are you getting ? Maybe you need to implement the required init with coder initialiser ?

Comment: @modalmusic There is nothing wrong with `let`, actually its best to use it whenever it makes sense with Swift (compiler will let you know if it sees you should replace a var with a let)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the responses. You're all correct - the bug had nothing to do with subclass initialisation, I'd just made some mistakes with as? stuff.

Comment: @modalmusic I don’t think it was the `let` that El Tomato didn’t like, but the variable name ‘Ci’. Firstly it’s not camel-case; secondly it’s not very descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code is fine, the bugs were due to something else. If anyone sees this - it is now that easy to add new attributes to a subclass - you don't have to faff around with super inits etc.

```
print(Ci.pitch)
```

will now give "middle C".